# Tableau: How to join new data source in existing tableau workbook

Tags: excel, datasource, join, tableau-api

I have a new data source and I want to join them into my existing Tableau so all the data and dashboard will be updated. Is it possible?

Comment: It is possible... but remember to bring one input sample, one expected output sample and what you try

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the data, you can :

- create a new data source
- join to the new data
- union to the existing data

It depends on what the new data is.